# BugSense Framework crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, bugsense

i used Bugsense framework in iPhone application to get the crashe logs, and it works fine.
but when i get the crash report from iTunes account, the crash report indicate that there is a crash in bugSense framework.

What this is mean? is it indicate that crashes in applications reported by bugSense ? or it is actual crash in the framework itself?

Please Help.

Thx

Comment: Please provide an example crash report. Without that it is not possible to give an answer.

Comment: Hello, 
This is the crash report link:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzRX2T-BHn-4azljMVNmbmRQZDQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may happen when there is no internet connection, try enable immediate dispatch in bug sense

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that this is a crash in their SDK. Sadly they perform non-async safe functions in their framework once the crash happened. See http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html for more details on what that means (in this case calling Objective-C code once a crash occurred is unsafe). You might want to contact them to make the fix this possible problem.

But the messages lower in the stack trace also indicate, that this is a crash that happened because of an uncaught exception occurred, which would normally cause another `Last Exception Backtrace` to appear on top of `Thread 0`. I am not sure if they have that functionality included. If they do, this causes that block only appear in their own crash report but not in the crash reports iOS creates. Then this is nothing to worry about, except that code above being bad as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled immediate dispatch in BugSense, this is probably the reason of this crash, as it isn't guaranteed to be safe.

For more info you can check this: https://github.com/bugsense/plcrashreporter-bugsense/wiki/Using-the-BugSense-2.x-iOS-library , section Enabling immediate dispatch